# Is it first time in history that ongoing war was halted for few hours to evacuate people?

Tags: russian-federation, india, history, ukraine

I am referring to Indian Prime Minister Modi second phone call to Putin during Russo-Ukraine conflicts, to get help to evacuate stranded Indian Students in Ukraine. So Putin halted his war for [6 hours](https://pipanews.com/russia-ukraine-war-modi-phone-call-to-putin-6-hours-leeway-for-indians-to-leave-russia-president-vladimir-putin-announces-6-hours-break-to-ukraine-war-after-pm-modi-phone-calls-to-him/).

Is it first time in history that ongoing war was halted for few hours to evacuate people?

Comment: Haven't seen this mentioned in either Russian or Western sources, so it seems like Indian propaganda or low quality sources drumming up some local ceasefire (seemingly around Kharkiv), if there even was one.

Comment: What is more certain is that some such students have died already https://www.nytimes.com/2022/03/02/world/europe/indian-student-ukraine-death.html And Russia is claiming that Ukraine is keeping them hostage https://www.ndtv.com/india-news/indian-students-kept-as-hostages-by-ukrainians-in-kharkiv-says-russia-2800139

Comment: Depends on your definition of "evacuate" - the March 2019 120-hour ceasefire in Syria [link](https://www.vox.com/2019/10/17/20919566/turkey-syria-us-ceasefire-erdogan-pence-kurds) might qualify

Comment: I cannot think of any special instance but I am pretty sure it's not.

Comment: Anyway, the university in Kharkiv got "cancelled" (Russian-world style) https://www.bbc.com/news/world-60597751 And the Indian government denied (Russian) reports that their students are being held hostage https://www.thehindubusinessline.com/news/national/no-reports-of-any-hostage-situation-in-kharkiv-says-mea/article65186106.ece

Comment: This pipanews article contains strange turns of phrase such as "the Ukrainian army is drinking water from three ponds" and "citizens on the battlefield is showing the dots for Russia". It also mentions an "Also Read:" article with no links. Smells like bad machine translation, or automatically generated, which fits the too-many-ads theme.

Comment: @BoppreH Or, just standard Indian English.

Comment: @GlenYates - No not all mainstream english Media in India is like that .This particular site is just exceptional and of very poor quality.Never heard about it.

Comment: @Fizz And 22 hours later the Hindu Businessline article now states: “No reports of any hostage situation in Kharkiv, says MEA: Clarification follows reports quoting Russian officials alleging that Ukrainian authorities were keeping Indian students from leaving.” Please note that in general anyone stuck in an active war zone might _feel_ like they are being held hostage because they just can’t easily run away from what is happening. If I had to wait hours (even days) at a border crossing I _might_ feel trapped like a hostage. But that is vastly different than being deliberately being a hostage.

Comment: @GlenYates A search for those phrases turned out nothing, so it's either a very poor literal translation, or machine-generated nonsense.

Comment: It's been reported that Russian troll farms have been instructed to focus all their efforts on India, so likely this is just the result of their work.

Comment: This smells wrong on every level.  You *cannot* negotiate a cease-fire with just one side of an on-going conflict.  Both sides have to agree, otherwise the remaining soldiers would take advantage of the cessation to counter-attack and then the side you negotiated with would be forced to break their cease-fire to defend themselves. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

According to more serious (but still Indian) sources relating on the matter (of this 2nd phone call), like [The Hindu reporting of today](https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/indians-told-to-rush-from-war-hit-kharkiv/article65184818.ece), no such cessation was agreed. At best:

> Moscow is considering a humanitarian corridor for foreign nationals stuck in Kharkiv

So it looks like pipanews.com = fake news.

On the other hand, the Indian foreign ministry has [confirmed](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2022/3/1/indian-student-killed-in-ukraine-amid-criticism-over-evacuation) the death of one Indian student in the shelling on Kharkiv.

Comment: Was 6 hours window provided all International students or just Indian students. No results come up for other international students except Indian. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @Ubihatt the window was not provided at all.

Comment: Insofar the promised humanitarian corridors didn't quite work out either. Mutual accusations of breaking the ceasefire, etc. https://edition.cnn.com/2022/03/05/europe/ukraine-russia-invasion-saturday-intl/index.html ; https://edition.cnn.com/2022/03/05/europe/ukraine-kherson-russian-occupation-cmd-intl/index.html

Comment: @Ubihatt How can you have a cease-fire "just for Indian students"?  It doesn't make sense, the Russians are shelling Ukrainian cities with artillery from many kilometers away, they can't exactly check passports and identities before firing.  A cease-fire affects everyone indiscriminately.

Comment: @RBarryYoung When no other countries were taking initiatives to bring back their own students back (including China) India started evacuating. Pakistan and Turkey students used Indian flags in city to take the bus towards boarder. P.M. Modi remains the only premier who spoke twice directly with Putin for peace and evacuating students. Also, student shared their experience that seeing Indian flag Ukrainians used to stop buses and Russian didn't harassed them but only upon reaching border - Border forces of Ukraine ill treated them.

Comment: @Peteris Yeah window wasn't provided but Indian Flag acted well. It also helped Pakistani and Turkey students equally to escape from inner city towards borders.

Answer (score 23):

For example, it was practiced in [2008-2009 conflict between Israel and Hamas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaza_War_(2008-2009)):

> Due to the number of civilian casualties and the deteriorating humanitarian situation, Israel faced significant international pressure for a ceasefire, the establishment of a humanitarian corridor, access to the population of Gaza and the lifting of the blockade.[253] On 7 January, Israel opened a humanitarian corridor to allow the shipment of aid into Gaza. The Israeli army agreed to interrupt fighting for three hours and Hamas agreed not to launch rockets during the pause.[254][255][256] Israel repeated the ceasefire either daily or every other day.

Answer (score 12):

This (assuming it happened, per Fizz's answer) is definitely not the first time a war has been halted for a few hours to allow evacuation of people. In fact, Russia has halted a war for a few days to allow evacuation of civilians.

In the Second Chechen War:

> December 6, 1999: Russian planes rained flyers today on the Chechen capital with an ultimatum to rebel fighters and civilians still holed up in the battered city: Leave or be destroyed.
>
> The Russian command warned that anyone in Grozny had until Saturday to flee before federal forces unleashed a massive artillery and air bombardment to smash the city into submission. It said a safe corridor would be open until Dec. 11 to let civilians escape.

[Source](https://apnews.com/article/02b63bc318b64ac6893a700769d75158)

EDIT: It looks like Russia [has done](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/europe/ukraine-russia-mariupol-humanitarian-corridors-b2029181.html) (or at least declared it is doing; Ukraine alleges violations) the same thing in Ukraine.

Comment: It seems more like a warning rather than an evacuation process to me,(personal opinion)

Comment: @AbhinavLenka how so? They did warn civilians to leave, but they also halted the invasion & provided a safe corridor.

Comment: In the '99 war it is more like an ultimatum given to the citizens to run away rather than bravely defend their own country so that they will face less resistance whereas the case now is pertaining to safe return of foreign individuals.

Comment: @AbhinavLenka I still don't see much of a difference. People who want to evacuate (which presumably includes all foreign individuals) can evacuate. People who want to stay and fight  can stay and fight (and will be treated as hostile fighters).

Comment: Civilians who refuse to leave their homes may be "treated as hostile fighters" but that doesn't make them so.  This sort of thing is the aggressor laying the groundwork for later claims they they aren't war criminals after they indiscriminately bomb civilians.

Comment: @EricNolan I still don't see the relevance. The question asks about whether a war has been halted to evacuate people, and that's what happened in this situation.

Comment: The Russians did this in Syria. I got the impression that the "rebels" were encouraged to head towards the Americans.

Answer (score 0):

The question does not specify anything about evacuating civilians, so the Christmas Truce might qualify, when they let each other evacuate their wounded from no man's land.